# Bot doesn't want to add a role when I react to message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a bot that will add role to a member when member reacts to a message.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction, member: discord.Member):
    ChID = '678640775747076097'
    if reaction.message != ChID:
        await member.send("Nope")
        return
    else:
        if member.reaction.emoji == ":white_check_mark:":
            Role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="672473925053055036")
            await client.add_roles(member, Role)
            await user.send("Success")
```

When I am reacting to message, I get this error:

```
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `on_raw_reaction_add` function shouldn't expect to receive a `member` argument, only a `payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent` argument.

Try this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    reaction_message_id = payload.message_id
    member = payload.member
    ChID = '678640775747076097'
    if reaction_message_id != ChID:
        await member.send("Nope")
        return
    else:
        if member.reaction.emoji == ":white_check_mark:":
            Role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="672473925053055036")
            await client.add_roles(member, Role)
            await user.send("Success")
```

As it is an example on how to the properties you'll need from the payload.

More info on the two methods and their signatures:

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add